# Highlighted button image is not showing in iOS 7

Tags: ios

UI Button highlighted button image is not showing in iOS 7.

It does work in iOS 6, but its not working in iOS 7.

Comment: I just ran into this problem with an old moth balled application. No code, everything was in Interface Builder, so I think it's valid question. I was able to solve the issue by changing the Type from "System" to "Custom" and my highlighted button images worked again.

Answer (score 2):

How you are setting image for highLightedState... if you are setting via interface builder make sure you have select right state from stateConfig in attribute inspector. You can set image for every state.
If you are setting it via code make sure you do like this

```
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateHighlighted]
```

**NOTE:**
If you have xib, please clean and build again. xib some time don't take effects of change. Better will be delete app from simulator or device and run again.

Comment: i have set the button type custom and set the stateconfig highlghted .but still it will show dark black color on click.

Comment: Clean and build again... better to reset app from simulator or device by deleting and installing again, if you are doing every thing right. Some time xibs don't take effect and we have to clean and build.

Comment: yes you are right its working now. i have delete the app from background then it will work again. :) thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

For me its working fine in ios7 as well as ios6 also. So try like this.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"highlight.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 50)];
[self.view addSubview:button];
```